# Apache fail to load django secret key from environment

Tags: python, django, apache

I have moved the secret key from the settings.py to /etc/environment

/etc/environment

```
SECRET_KEY='tne@n#^^%pp2h3mnwy2=94vuc!d99h=ww69tttf2n#_ypcjk)h'
```

In my project's settings.py

```
SECRET_KEY=os.environ['SECRET_KEY']
```

This is my error in apache error_log file

```
KeyError: 'SECRET_KEY', referer: http://anime.moxware.com/
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: I wouldn't have thought `/etc/environment` is a safe place to store this as it will be available system wide. Was there a reason you moved it from the `settings.py`?

Comment: @arco444, I m just trying to separate it from the settings.py since its a recommended practice. So Anyway any idea on why that environment variable is unavailable in my python script?

Comment: @Adrian, tried in both fedora 21 and Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, both gave the same result.